# Greasemonkey doesn't execute again after form prints result

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, greasemonkey

I'm using greasemonkey to manipulate a form on an existing web page. (autofill)

The action attribute of the form is itself, once submitted it prints a success message above the submit button.

What I'm trying to do is, once the form is submitted - I want to redirect the browser to another page. But this doesnt work with greasemonkey. Nothing happens.

I wrote a code to detect when the page is submitted, but doesnt work after the form is submitted.

```
getData("goingback"); //pulls the goingback data from database using ajax

if (goingback == "yes") {
    window.location = "index.php";
} else {
//business as usual

 // manipulate the form and get it ready for submission

sendPost("goback","yes"); // this function sends data to a php to be handled via ajax

//ajax stores the data in database

//the form is submitted using a timer and .click();

var submission = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 5000;
setTimeout(function() {
$('button[value="submit"]:first').click();
}, submission);
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you set the value of `goingback`?

Comment: stored in database via ajax (right before submission) and pulled via ajax when the page loads (supposed to happen after submission)

Comment: `localStorage` should do the job, just remember to clear the variable.  A recommend checking the DOM instead, however, if possible.

Comment: It's quite likely that's the bit that's not working - but we can't really help too much unless you show us how it's working :)

Comment: Everything works without submitting the page, ajax pulls data - checks it. But after submission, it doesnt. Once I reload the page after the submission, it pulls the data and does what I want it to do.

Comment: I've tried to explain it a little bit more in the last edit.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear; we might need to see the actual page itself.  But, it sounds like the page is submitting the form via AJAX, and not a full post.

In that case, your script won't refire.  Instead, monitor the page for the success message.  Here's one way:

Suppose the success message is like this:

```
<div id="post_status">
    <h2>Some one set us up the (data) bomb!</h2>
</div>
```

where the `<h2>` is added after the form posts.

Then this code will redirect after the post happens:

```
var postChkTimer = setInterval (checkForPostDoneNode, 200);

function checkForPostDoneNode () {
    var postDoneNode = $("#post_status h2");
    if (postDoneNode.length) {
        window.location.assign ("index.php");
    }
}
```

There is no need for that `getData("goingback")`  or 
`sendPost("goback","yes")`.   Also that *looks* like it's setting `goback` but *checking* `goingback` -- which could be a problem.  Although it is not the problem causing the behavior as described in the question.